# How to transform tsx to js on saving use PhpStorm or WebStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, babeljs, jsx, tsx

I have a .tsx file that automatically transforms to .jsx, also I have a file watcher that transforms .jsx to js, but the file watcher doesn't pick up .jsx file under .tsx, if I create .jsx separately - it works.

[image: File Watcher Settings]

Comment: It's un-clear what you are asking.  Refer to [ask].  Provide a [mcve].   You didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed the question.

Comment: please can you provide screenshots of your file watchers settings?

Comment: I've attached, thank you